# How do I prove that if $\gcd(n,m)$ divides $a-b$, then $x\equiv a \pmod n$ and $x\equiv b \pmod m $ has a solution?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n,m$ be positive integers $>1$.

Assume that $\gcd(n,m)\mid (a-b)$

Then how do I show that $x\equiv a \pmod n$ and $x\equiv b \pmod m$ has a solution?

I"m struggling with this for an hour and I can't find a solution..

Comment: [This](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FChinese_remainder_theorem&ei=V4QxVMWRLoKxuQSlq4DgDQ&usg=AFQjCNEStgJUmIcEim90ebybRgtBmDpX9Q&bvm=bv.76802529,d.c2E) may be of some help.

Comment: @user170039 Chinese Remainder Theorem cannot be applied.. since $n,m$ need not to be relatively prime

Comment: Break the problem up so that you *do* have relative primality.

Comment: @linearalgebrareviewr: It is not necessary. There will be a solution $x_0$ which is unique modulo $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$.

Comment: @anon I tried that too. Say n=ds ,m=dt. Then I get a solution x=a(mod s) and y=b(mod t). I don't have any idea how to deform this to a solution to the original one.

Comment: @user170039 How do I prove that? Would you please give me some details?

Comment: @linearalgebrareviewr: You have done everything. You have proved that $x \equiv a$ $(\operatorname{mod}s)$ and  $x \equiv b$ $(\operatorname{mod}t)$. Now noting that $\operatorname{gcd}(s,t)=1$ you apply CRT.

Comment: @user170039 I don't get it. If CRT is applied, then I get $x$ such that x=a(mod s) and x=b(mod t). NOT x=a(mod n) and x=a(mod m)

Comment: I wish I would have seen this earlier.  If your moduli are all relatively prime the CRT tells you that a unique solution exists and the solution is congruent modulo product of system moduli.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assume $m>n$.  Let $g=\gcd{(m,n)}$.  Since $g|(a-b)$, there exists an integer $k$ such that $a-b=gk$

Since $g=\gcd{(m,n)}$, $gk_1=m, gk_2=n$ for integers $k_1, k_2$.

Finally, since $x\equiv a\pmod{n}$, then $$x-a=nb=gk_2b$$ and thus $x\equiv a\pmod{g}$ as well

Now, suppose that there is no solution to the system.  Then 
$$x\not\equiv a\pmod{n}$$$$ x\equiv b\pmod{m}$$
is one case then.  This implies
$$x-a=nb+c, \text{ where }b,c\in \mathbb{Z}, 0\le c\lt n$$
$$x-b=md, \text{ where } d\in \mathbb{Z}$$
Now look at $(x-b)-(x-a)$
$$(x-b)-(x-a)=md-(nb+c)$$
$$a-b=gk_1d-gk_2b-c$$
$$a-b=g(k_1d-k_2b)-c$$
Note that it is possible that $c=g$, since $g\le n$.  But 
$$x\not\equiv a\pmod{n}\Rightarrow x-a\neq nb\Rightarrow x-a\neq gk_2b$$And thus $x\not\equiv a\pmod{g}$. This implies that $c\neq g$ since 
$$x-a=nb+c\Rightarrow x-a=gk_2b+g \Rightarrow x-a=g(k_2b+1)$$ which contradicts the fact that $x\not\equiv a\pmod{g}$.

But we have the initial condition that $a-b=gk$ for some integer $k$, but here, since letting $k=k_1d-k_2b$ gives us $a-b=gk+c$, we have a contradiction.  Therefore, our assumption that there is no solution is wrong and the system has a solution.

Comment: I totally don't get it. I can only see that the condition says that $g$ divides $c$ but nothing else...

Comment: I edited...see if you get it now.

Comment: No, What if $g$ divides $c$? Why is it a contradiction?

Comment: it is a contradiction because $g$ can not divide $c$.  If $x\equiv a\pmod{n}$ it is necessarily true that $x\equiv a\pmod{g}$, since $$x-a=nb=gk_2b$$ and this implies that $x\equiv a\pmod{g}$.  It wasn't apparent in the proof, so I'll fix when I get a moment.

Comment: I fixed the argument, so I hope this helps.

Comment: why the recent downvote?

Answer (score 1):

In fact it can be proven that the system 
$\begin{align}
x&\equiv a\mod(n)\\
x&\equiv b\mod(m) 
\end{align}$
has a solution $x$ if and only if $(n,m)|a-b$. The $\Rightarrow)$ proof is obvious, but the other direction, which is precisely OP's question, is slightly less obvious.

Let $d=(n,m)$, then by Bezout's identity we know that there exists $s,t\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $ns+mt=d$. Given $d|a-b$, then we know $a-b=dk$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore we have $nsk+mtk=a-b$. Rearrange the expression and we have $m(-tk)+a=nsk+b$. Let $x=m(-tk)+a$, we have $x-a=m(-tk)$, which immediately means $x\equiv a \mod(m)$. On the other hand we have $x=nsk+b$, which gives us $x-b=nsk$, which entails $x\equiv b \mod(n)$.

Answer (score -1):

Write $n=\prod p^{e_p}$ and $m=\prod p^{v_p}$. For each $p$ we want

$$x\equiv a\bmod p^{e_p} \quad{\rm and}\quad x\equiv b\bmod p^{v_p} \quad {\rm given} \quad a\equiv b\bmod p^{\min\{e_p,v_p\}}.$$

So set $c_p:=a$ if $e_p\ge v_p$ and $c_p:=b$ if $e_p<v_p$ and then solve the system $x\equiv c_p\bmod p^{\max\{e_p,v_p\}}$.